# React Componets Not Displaying On Server

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, host

I have hosted my react app in https://dev.newrohanamotors.lk/frontend/ here.

But it doesn't load the login page.

But It will change the title of the page.

**Working well in local.**

Can you please help me ?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building as a production build and try again, Sometimes I also face a similar kinda situation, It's just that you have to reinstall all the supporting packages and build an optimized build and they try deploying. Coz, Its subjective reasons may differ from case to case!

Comment: Console log shows https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ error, is this library in your bundle?

Comment: alextrastero, nope it's a cdn

Comment: @Giriraj, yeah I did a production build. Also I have tested with a fresh react app. it works fine on server

Comment: @PrasadChathuranga I guess its a react-router error ! Try to fix that

Comment: @Giriraj do you know a way to fix it ? It doesn't show an error about routing : (